# C# - Sum integer in Array using recursive

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, recursion

So i'm currently trying to calculate the sum of all bags in the array using a recursive method. I'm sure it's easy, but I can't seem to get my head around it. Any assistance would be appreciated! - Cheers.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Bag> bags = new List<Bag>();
        bags.Add(new Bag("Blue", 25));
        bags.Add(new Bag("Red", 35));
        bags.Add(new Bag("White", 30));
        int totalVolume = CalcTotalVolume(bags);
        Console.WriteLine("Total volume of bags: {0}", totalVolume);
    }
    static int CalcTotalVolume(List<Bag> bagList)
    {
        //resursive method
        //1. base case is when the list is empty
        if (bagList.Count == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            List<int> subList = bagList.GetRange(1, bagList.Volume - 1);
            int subTotal = CalcTotalVolume(subList);
            int total = bagList[1] + subTotal;
            return total;
        }
    }

}//end of class Program
class Bag
{

    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    public Bag(string co, int vo)
    {
        Colour = co;
        Volume = vo;
    }
}
```

Comment: please ensure your code compiles fully prior to posting. there are `3` statements which to me seems like it will not compile.

Comment: @Aominè that's my problem though? i'm showing what i've tried so far which are those 3 statements

Comment: Lists are 0 based, so bagList[1] will get the second bag in the list (not the first). Also, you are subtracting from bagList.Volume to get the sublist. This doesn't really make a lot of sense. bagList is a List so it doesn't have a Volume. You really just want the length of the list (bagList.Count - 1).

Comment: @Brian I did do that, but I'm getting the error `Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type` - everything I do just brings me another error lol

Comment: You are also trying to assign a List<Bag> to a List<int>, this is probably where you are getting the type conversion error. Using the var keyword helps prevent these kinds of basic mistakes and helps your keyboard live longer :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously a loop is a lot more efficient, but just for a kata, this is sort of interesting...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Bag> bags = new List<Bag>();
            bags.Add(new Bag("Blue", 25));
            bags.Add(new Bag("Red", 35));
            bags.Add(new Bag("White", 30));
            int totalVolume = CalcTotalVolume(bags);
            Console.WriteLine("Total volume of bags: {0}", totalVolume);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        static int CalcTotalVolume(IEnumerable<Bag> bags)
        {
            //resursive method
            //1. base case is when the list is empty
            var bag = bags.FirstOrDefault();
            if (bag == null) return 0;

            var subList = bags.Skip(1);
            return bag.Volume + CalcTotalVolume(subList);
        }
    }

    class Bag
    {

        public string Colour { get; set; }
        public int Volume { get; set; }
        public Bag(string co, int vo)
        {
            Colour = co;
            Volume = vo;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That's the exact result I want! - but it's not through a recursive method. :(

Comment: Why do you think it's not recursive?

Comment: I thought recursion means that a function calls itself in a loop?

Comment: CalcTotalVolume does call itself. See this line `return bag.Volume + CalcTotalVolume(subList);`

Answer (score 1):

It would be interesting to know what kind of recursion you want. For example, the following also uses a recursive method but it amounts to a simple summing loop:

```
class Bag
{
    public string Colour { get; }
    public int Volume { get; }
    public Bag(string c, int v)
    {
        Colour = c;
        Volume = v;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static int CalcTotalVolumeIdx(List<Bag> bags, int i, int sum)
    {
        return (i >= bags.Count) ? sum :
            CalcTotalVolumeIdx(bags, i + 1, sum + bags[i].Volume);
    }

    static int CalcTotalVolume(List<Bag> bags)
    {
        return CalcTotalVolumeIdx(bags, 0, 0);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Bag> bags = new List<Bag>();
        bags.Add(new Bag("Blue", 25));
        bags.Add(new Bag("Red", 35));
        bags.Add(new Bag("White", 30));
        int totalVolume = CalcTotalVolume(bags);
        Console.WriteLine("Total volume of bags: {0}", totalVolume);
    }
}
```

As a side note, F# would actually compile the function CalcTotalVolumeIdx() into a while loop since this type of recursion is a well-known pattern that can be efficiently converted.

*Edited to reflect Brian's comment. Thank you!*

Comment: This won't actually compile, Bag does not have a implicit conversion to int. You need to do `sum + bags[i].Volume`. Also, you can get rid of the sum parameter and just do this instead `: bags[i].Volume + CalcTotalVolumeIdx(bags, i + 1);`

Comment: Corrected the Volume part. Thanks for pointing it out! As to the other suggestion, yes, you can do that but it is not tail-recursive. Perhaps C# does not usually support it anyway but in F#, for example, the distinction is quite important.

Comment: I just learned about tail-recursive a few days ago. I don't think it is a C# thing since I can't imagine anybody writing something like this in C# would actually use a recursive method. I'm not that familiar with F#, but I think this is a common pattern for that language which is why they probably recognize it and handle it appropriately.